# WPF: Binding the same style from itself

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, styles

How does one call a Style (FolderStyle) from itself (from FolderStyle)?

So basically I have a TreeView that represents an object tree. In the tree there are folders and different objects. Each folder can contain every type of object and also other folders. Each object type and folders have their own style (because you have to display the objects different parameters and other things).
What I did was bind the TreeView ItemContainerStyle to a FolderStyle

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootNodes}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FolderStyle}"/>
```

Then in the folder style I check the children of the folder and decide which style every separate child should get via triggers

```
<Style x:Key="FolderStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ObjectType}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Header">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="0,0,3,0" Width="16" Source="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Folder}}"/>
                            <TextBlock>Folder</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView},Path=ItemContainerStyle}"/> //Problem is in this line. This exact way of doing it will give you an exception that says that the object already has a logical parent and you have to unbind it
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ObjectType}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ObjectATemplate}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ObjectType}" Value="3">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ObjectBTemplate}"/>

        ...And so on
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I need the child folder style to be exactly the same as the root one because the tree could be infinite (You can make any level of hierarchy with folders and objects).All of the styles work except the child folder one.I have tried to bind the folder ItemContainerStyle to FolderStyle but it can't resolve it. The presented way runs but doesn't apply the Style (It displays the object type in the tree).

How can I apply the folder style to child folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is not about applying styles, but with `Header` property, which is trying to assign same `StackPanel` for all Headers  hence exception. Workoaround is using `HeaderTemplate`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ObjectType}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Margin="0,0,3,0" Width="16" Source="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Folder}}"/>
                        <TextBlock>Folder</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
           ...
```

I also recommend using `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for this class of problems.

Comment: It's not the headers that are the problem, it's the itemsource. I can't get child folders to be the exact same as the root folder because i can't bind the style to itself. The headers are actually the thing that always works=)

Comment: So `object already has a logical parent exception ...` causing ItemsSource?

Comment: Wow, the header was actually the problem! Now everything works! Thanks a lot! Here's how it [was meant to be](http://i.imgur.com/fFdBb48.png)